# How to inject a Spring 3 Bean into a JSF 2 Converter

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, converters

I am trying to `@javax.naming.Inject` a Spring 3 Bean called `WtvrBean` into a JSF 2 `@FacesConverter`.

Both the Bean and the Converter are on the same package. And, in my spring's applicationContext.xml, I am scanning this package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my-package" />
```

But this is not working. For sure, the JSF 2 internal class that uses the converter is 
definitely not in `my-package`.

For instance, if I remove the `@ManagedBean` from a JSF 2 ManagedBean, and replace it to `@org.springframework.stereotype.Component` or `@Controller`, the `WtvrBean` can be `@Inject`ed on this ManagedBean, by using Spring WebFlow.

Well, as far as I know, there is no such thing as a `@Converter` stereotype in Spring.

I know I can use

```
FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context).getBean("WtvrBean")
```

But, with that approach, the coupling between the web app and the spring is getting more tight. (annotations are metadata, and are not even considered dependency by some authors).

I am using `FacesContextUtils` so far, if there is no better solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to inject beans into instances of a class, these instances have to be spring-managed. I.e. spring has to instantiate them. And this is not happening, so - no, you can't inject there.

But this is because you register the converter within jsf. You can skip that:

```
@Component("myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter { .. }
```

And then, if you are using the spring `<el-resolver>`:

```
converter="#{myConverter}"
```

So that will do it. It has worked for me.

(A workaround worth mentioning is that you can do it by using [aspectj weaving and `@Configurable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s08.html), but I'd prefer your `FacesContextUtils` approach. The weaving modifies classes so that they become spring managed even if they are not instantiated by spring.)

Comment: Hi. I don't want my converter to be eligible for injection. There's a Bean called WtvrBean, and I want the bean to be injected IN the converter. I'll take a look at aspectj.

Comment: @bluefoot sorry, that's what I meant to say - it's not possible to inject other beans into it.

Comment: @bluefoot - oops, I forgot I had actually done this.. see my update

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to do this with a forClass converter?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Strangely enough I hit this problem last night, and have used your answer to solve it this morning. I found it quite odd that it was exactly a year later that I needed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@FacesConverter(value = "examTypeConverter")
@Named
```

Simple answer.

Comment: A huge -1: OP is using Spring, not CDI. The `@Named` is specific to CDI, not Spring. The Spring way is -as answered by Bozho- using `@Component` which does indeed essentially the same as you said. Whoever upvoted this answer has to reconsider his upvote.

Comment: Spring 3 supports `@Named` injection, though it's not calling the CDI container to inject the bean/resource.

Answer (score 0):

hey i was facing the same problem that spring beans are not getting injected in the JSF Converter.

then by googling about it i found the answers that after JSF 2.2 we can make converters as jsf managed bean. and then we can inject the spring dependency.
it solved my problem.

```
 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 public class CustomerByName implements Converter {

      @ManagedProperty(value = "#{customerDao}")
      private CustomerDao customerDao;
```

and in your jsf page use it like a managed bean

```
 converter="#{customerByName}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Add @Scope annotation (eg with "request" parameter) to your managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@Scope("request")
public class MyBean {
....
}
```

Comment: that was not what I asked. My Managed Bean is ok, just like I wrote. The problem is in the Converter.